# Ethereum Pending Transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain

I am trying to send 2  transactions.

> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1],
>   value: web3.toWei(5, "ether")})
>
> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1],
>   value: web3.toWei(5, "ether")})

The transactions are getting submitted and getting the hash of the transaction

```
INFO [08-25|21:14:21] Submitted transaction
fullhash=0xe1b58ddcb6d8c3f3a8308e0eb275f10c0c3b7bd8807cd24ff6a315a3917ab2a5 recipient=0x939f34bc9253a62927871c889bcf62f398d264a6 INFO [08-25|21:14:29] Submitted transaction
fullhash=0x33ca6bb00a70de13bd8b1fdec5d0a7995ad09a90e416ac8ab686fc650a324331 recipient=0x939f34bc9253a62927871c889bcf62f398d264a6 INFO [08-25|21:14:57] Updated mining threads threads=1 INFO [08-25|21:14:57] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000 INFO [08-25|21:14:57] Starting mining operation INFO [08-25|21:14:57] Commit new mining work
number=1 txs=2 uncles=0 elapsed=73.574ms
```

But the transactions are still in pending state.
as they get listed in the following query

> eth.pendingTransactions

So my question is

1) When will my transactions will execute and the transfer amount will be reflected?

2) Do I need to send any command?

I am using private blockchain and using geth

Any comment or suggestion will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you aren't mining yet on your private node. Run `miner.start(1)` on your node to mine some blocks.

Comment: When i run the `miner.start(1)` command it is returning a `null` value.
And below is the log
`INFO [08-27|18:45:18] Updated mining threads                   threads=1
INFO [08-27|18:45:18] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000
INFO [08-27|18:45:18] Starting mining operation 
INFO [08-27|18:45:18] Commit new mining work                   number=1 txs=2 uncles=0 elapsed=1.067ms
`

Comment: It hasn't finished mining the block yet. You will know it is done when you see something like this in the logs: 
```INFO [08-27|14:35:13] Successfully sealed new block            number=853 hash=4195a0…2865c0
INFO [08-27|14:35:13]  mined potential block                  number=853 hash=4195a0…2865c0```

The following may be useful: ```eth.getBlock('latest').number``` to see the latest block number mined and ```eth.getBlock('pending').transactions``` to prove that your txn is in the next block to be mined. Null is normal return code for ```miner.start()```

Comment: Thanks a Lot. I will wait and comment on this thread if it doesn't after a certain time.
 i have set `"difficulty": "0x4000"` in my genesis file.
How long does it take?Also is there a certain threshold only after which they will be put in block?
I just read some log `INFO [08-27|18:45:18] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000

Comment: I used ```"difficulty": "40"``` in mine to make things run quicker :) If this is the first time you are mining on this PC then you may need to wait for the DAG to be created (though you would see relevant INFO messages in log telling you the progress of this).

Comment: One more thought @Vishal10 - how much RAM does your node have? Min recommended is 2Gb (and I get similar symptoms - i.e. takes ages to start mining - if I use less than this)

Comment: I changed my  script to `geth --datadir /home/vishal/Ethereum/Impl/geth/privchain3 --dev --nodiscover --mine --minerthreads 1 --maxpeers 0 --verbosity 3   --unlock 0 --password /home/vishal/Ethereum/Impl/password.sec   --rpc`
And it started creating the DAG. also i lowered the difficulty to 40 as you told it worked. Thanks a lot :)